# Android Running Service indefinitely recommended?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

My application has a service that collects data through bluetooth and stores in a file locally. However the code for turning on the bluetooth and pairing is in the activity.

Am planning to bring the pairing part logic into the service as well, but i do not want to kill the service ever after exiting the application. The next time when my mobile comes within the bluetooth range, since it is already paired it will start collecting data.

Is it recommended to make the service run at the background indefinitely? 
Does this will really drain up the battery? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if there exist a broadcast intent sent from the system everytime it gets connected to a bluetooth. If so, register a BroadcastReceiver on your Manifest and start your service when the intent is received. If it doesnt exist, then you should keep a running service hearing bluetooth connections or whatever you hear and act accordingly when a connection is detected. Keep in mind that even your service is not closed by you once started, Android could kill it whenver it needs to free memory and will be recreated later on.